# touch.location responsive coordinations

Tags: swift, xcode

i want to calculate the touch.location to be responsive when send it to another phones

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped = false
    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: self.imageView)
        print (lastPoint.x)
    }
}
```

Notice the black line at the bottom of the screen on the iPhone 8 is centered on the iPhone 11 Pro Max

on iPhone 8 Simulator
[image: on iPhone 8 Simulator]

on iPhone 11 Pro Max Simulator
[image: on iPhone 8 Simulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're doing something like this:

1. Get the point from phone A, which is 100 x 100 pixels. The point is at x: 30, y: 40.
2. Display the point on phone B, which is 200 x 200 pixels.

The point will be closer to the top left because CGPoint(x: 30, y: 40) is closer to the top left on the phone that has a higher pixel density.

Instead, try this:
1. Get the point from phone A, which is 100 x 100 pixels. Then divide by the height and width. The point is CGPoint(x: 0.3, y: 0.4).
2. Display the point on phone B by multiplying by the width and height. 0.3 * 200 = 60, 0.4 * 200 = 80. Now the the point will display correctly.

This will only work if the two phones have the same aspect ratio, otherwise it will stretch the image to fill the target phone.

Comment: Thank you lifesaver <3